# How do I both remove duplicates and filter blank entries in a ArrayCollection?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, duplicates, arraycollection

I can get the following code to removed duplicates.

```
private function removeDuplicates(item:Object):Boolean {
            var returnValue:Boolean = false;

        if (!myObject.hasOwnProperty(item.myVariable)){
                myObject[item.myVariable] = item;
                returnValue = true;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
```

But when I add the following code to the function the function not only fails to filter blank entries in the ArrayCollection, but also no longer removes duplicates.

```
private function removeDuplicates(item:Object):Boolean {
            var returnValue:Boolean = false;

        if (!myObject.hasOwnProperty(item.myVariable && item.myVariable != "")){
                myObject[item.myVariable] = item;
                returnValue = true;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
```

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You set your parentheses wrongly. `myObject.hasOwnProperty(item.myVariable && item.myVariable != "")` equals `myObject.hasOwnProperty(true)`, because the expression is evaluated before passing it into the function. You want to do this:

```
 if (!myObject.hasOwnProperty(item.myVariable) && (item.myVariable != "")) {
    myObject[item.myVariable] = item;
    returnValue = true;
 }
```